# How to approach this: Percentage change in one KPI leading to change in other KPIs?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, probability

I want to know how can I approach or model this problem. I have 7 KPIs (3 of them dependent on each other) and one main KPI (total 8 KPIs). I want to understand effect of these 7 KPIs on the main KPIs.

End goal is to make the statement, if you vary KPI_1 by xx.xx %, main_KPI will vary by yy.yy%.
Can I model this with linear regression, find coefficients or is there any better approach?

Comment: regression yes, linear maybe. For example polynomial regression is an option

Answer (score 1):

In linear regression models (aka OLS), you can interpret the estimated coefficient(s) as the percentage change in case $y$ and $x$ are log-transformed using the *natural* log (see [this post "Both dependent/response variable and independent/predictor variable(s) are log-transformed"](https://data.library.virginia.edu/interpreting-log-transformations-in-a-linear-model/) or see also [this post](https://learneconomicsonline.com/blog/archives/1095)).

For a model like:

$$ log_e(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 log_e(x) + u,$$

the interpretation would be: "if $x$ changes by one percent, $y$ changes by $\beta_1$ percent on average". This also works in a multivariate setting (with more than one $x$).

Comment: but what about dependency between variables? Few of the KPIs are highly dependent on each other, in that case, how do I take care of it with LR? apart from LR do you suggest any other approach?